# GROUP BY after UNION ALL doesn't group the result

Tags: mysql, group-by, union-all

I read few posts here on SO but I could not find a solution for my problem.

I want to merge 3 result sets into one but it seems GROUP BY doesn't allow me to group them. Instead the columns get overridden.

Here my MYSQL query:

```
SELECT spent.cid AS cid, spent.clientname AS clientname, spent.sumyearone AS sumyearone, spent.sumyeartwo AS sumyeartwo, spent.sumyearthree AS sumyearthree
FROM (
    SELECT yearone.cid AS cid, yearone.clientname AS clientname, yearone.sum AS sumyearone, 0 AS sumyeartwo, 0 AS sumyearthree
        FROM (
            ...
        ) AS yearone
    GROUP BY yearone.cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yeartwo.cid AS cid, yeartwo.clientname AS clientname, 0 AS sumyearone, yeartwo.sum AS sumyeartwo, 0 AS sumyearthree
       FROM (
           ...
       ) AS yeartwo
    GROUP BY yeartwo.cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yearthree.cid AS cid, yearthree.clientname AS clientname, 0 AS sumyearone, 0 AS sumyeartwo, yearthree.sum AS sumyearthree
        FROM (
            ...
        ) AS yearthree
    GROUP BY yearthree.cid
) AS spent
GROUP BY spent.cid
ORDER BY spent.cid DESC
```

If I run the query with `GROUP BY spent.cid` I get the following outcome

```
cid    clientname    sumyearone    sumyeartwo    sumyearthree
50     Jon Doe       1083          0             0
```

but if I run it without `GROUP BY spent.cid` I get the three correct return values:

```
cid    clientname    sumyearone    sumyeartwo    sumyearthree
50     Jon Doe       1083          0             0
50     Jon Doe       0             1602          0
50     Jon Doe       0             0             1367
```

What I want though is:

```
cid    clientname    sumyearone    sumyeartwo    sumyearthree
50     Jon Doe       1083          1602          1367
```

PS: I get the similar result if I use `null` instead of 0 for the field declaration (i.e. `null AS sumyeartwo`)

Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your query seems overly complex and I'm left wondering if there isn't a simpler way of writing it.

Comment: Hi Tim I'm wondering the same.  You should see the queries in the FROM statements :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` along with `GROUP BY` to get these numbers, e.g.:

```
SELECT spent.cid AS cid, spent.clientname AS clientname, SUM(spent.sumyearone) AS sumyearone, SUM(spent.sumyeartwo) AS sumyeartwo, SUM(spent.sumyearthree) AS sumyearthree
FROM (
    SELECT yearone.cid AS cid, yearone.clientname AS clientname, yearone.sum AS sumyearone, 0 AS sumyeartwo, 0 AS sumyearthree
        FROM (
            ...
        ) AS yearone
    GROUP BY yearone.cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yeartwo.cid AS cid, yeartwo.clientname AS clientname, 0 AS sumyearone, yeartwo.sum AS sumyeartwo, 0 AS sumyearthree
       FROM (
           ...
       ) AS yeartwo
    GROUP BY yeartwo.cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yearthree.cid AS cid, yearthree.clientname AS clientname, 0 AS sumyearone, 0 AS sumyeartwo, yearthree.sum AS sumyearthree
        FROM (
            ...
        ) AS yearthree
    GROUP BY yearthree.cid
) AS spent
GROUP BY spent.cid, spent.clientname
ORDER BY spent.cid DESC
```

Comment: I will try your solution once I'm back on my laptop Darshan